# Summarize collocate frequencies more concisely

Tags: r, dplyr

In this toy dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(left = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), 
                     node = c("xxx", "yyy", "xxx", "xxx", "yyy", "yyy", "xxx","yyy"), 
                     right = c("c", "d", "d", "d", "c", "c", "d", "d")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to summarize frequencies of collocates both on the `left` and on the `right` of the `node` forms **in a concise way**. The way I'm doing it does produce the expected frequencies on both sides:

```
df_l <- df %>%
  group_by(node, left) %>%
  summarise(n_left = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(n_left)) %>%
  select(c(3,2,1))

df_r <- df %>%
  group_by(node, right) %>%
  summarise(n_right = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(n_right))

df_all <- left_join(df_l, df_r, by = "node")
# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   node [2]
  n_left left  node  right n_right
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int>
1      3 a     xxx   d           3
2      3 a     xxx   c           1
3      3 a     yyy   c           2
4      3 a     yyy   d           2
5      1 b     xxx   d           3
6      1 b     xxx   c           1
7      1 b     yyy   c           2
8      1 b     yyy   d           2
```

The problem is that the way the frquencies are displayed is anything but concise - in fact there are numerous duplicates for the `left`/`n_left` and, respectively, `right`/`n_right` columns. The **output I'm looking for** is without any redundancies, like this:

```
#     n_left left  node  right n_right
#     <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int>
#  1      3 a     xxx   d           3
#  2      1 b     xxx   c           1
#  3      3 a     yyy   c           2
#  4      1 b     yyy   d           2
```

Any idea how that can be achieved?

Comment: Maybe there's a context I'm unfamiliar with, but how are you deciding what to keep? Why do you keep row 1 but not row 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshaping the data lets you rethink how you can do the aggregation all at once. The `select` call at the end could certainly be improved upon so it isn't manual—changing names and rearranging based on containing "left", for example—but this should be a start.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(left, right), names_to = "side", values_to = "letter") %>%
  count(node, side, letter) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = node, names_from = side, values_from = c(letter, n),
                     values_fn = list) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(-node) %>%
  select(n_left, left = letter_left, node, right = letter_right, n_right)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   n_left left  node  right n_right
#>    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int>
#> 1      3 a     xxx   c           1
#> 2      1 b     xxx   d           3
#> 3      3 a     yyy   c           2
#> 4      1 b     yyy   d           2
```

Comment: Thanks, great job! Just one more question: what if, say, the `left`  side is longer than the `right` side? Like in this data: `structure(list(left = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b"), node = c("xxx", "yyy", "xxx", "xxx", "yyy", "yyy", "xxx","yyy"), 
                     right = c("c", "d", "d", "d", "c", "c", "d", "d")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: I think that's where my question about the context would come in

Comment: No, there's no special context. All I need is remove identical (aka duplicated) **pairs** of values in the `n_left`/`left`  and, respectively, `n_right`/`right` columns

Answer (score 2):

This comes close... Perhaps it is good enough for you, else it might inspire someone to build onto.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars = "node")
dcast(df.melt, node + value ~ paste0("n_", variable), value.var = "value", fun.aggregate = length)
#    node value n_left n_right
# 1:  xxx     a      3       0
# 2:  xxx     b      1       0
# 3:  xxx     c      0       1
# 4:  xxx     d      0       3
# 5:  yyy     a      3       0
# 6:  yyy     b      1       0
# 7:  yyy     c      0       2
# 8:  yyy     d      0       2
```